# How to merge two Excel workbook into one workbook in C#?

Tags: c#

Let us consider that I have two Excel files (Workbooks) in local. Each Excel workbook is having 3 worksheets.

Lets say WorkBook1 is having Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3

Workbook2 is having Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3.

So here I need to merge these two excel workbook into one and the new excel workbook that is let's say Workbook3 which will have total 6 worksheets (combination of workbook1 and workbook2).

I need the code that how to perform this operation in c# without using any third party tool. If the third party tool is free version then its fine.

Comment: Did you search for any methods for programmatic access to excel workbooks at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sample that joins two books into a new one, hope it will give you an idea:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection; 


namespace MergeWorkBooks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();

            app.Visible = true;
            app.Workbooks.Add("");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"c:\MyWork\WorkBook1.xls");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"c:\MyWork\WorkBook2.xls");


            for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
            {
                int count = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count;

                app.Workbooks[i].Activate();
                for (int j=1; j <= count; j++)
                {
                    Excel._Worksheet ws = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
                    ws.Select(Type.Missing);
                    ws.Cells.Select();

                    Excel.Range sel = (Excel.Range)app.Selection;
                    sel.Copy(Type.Missing);

                    Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets.Add(
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
                        );

                    sheet.Paste(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                }


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I have added two workbooks but where I will create the third workbook and there I have to store the both. Please guide me because I am starter in programming....

Comment: See: app.Workbooks.Add(""); It's the book that collects worksheets of the two others.

Comment: 1) Create a console app 2) Add a link to Excel.Appkiation 3) Delete everything from your file and then copy and paste my code. 4) There are three lines in my code that start with `app.Workbooks.Add(`. The first line is a new book that will collect worksheets. Change the paths in the two next lines to your workbooks location. ---P.S It's just a test sample that only gives you an idea "how to" and it is not supposed to be used productively.

Comment: Hi,
This is fine for me and also thankful to you that you are giving me responses but the problem is when I am running this application, then automatically existing two and newly generated workbook is opening but I need only to open the new one not the existing two workbooks. And in the new sheet it was also having their default three sheets apart from merged sheets. So I need only merged sheets. Please help me then I will thankful to you.

Comment: I just gave you an idea so that you be able to implement what you need. Just record a macros in the Microsoft Excel and see what code it generates. Then translate te VB code into a C#. You can close the books after merging, you can delete useless sheets in the new book and rearrange useful ones, you can make the exel app visible not before, but after all the things done, you can even keep it invisible for all the session and save the new book as an excel file, whatever.

Answer (score 3):

An easier solution is to **copy the worksheets themselves**, and not their cells.

This method takes any number of excel file paths and copy them into a new file:

```
private static void MergeWorkbooks(string destinationFilePath, params string[] sourceFilePaths)
{
  var app = new Application();
  app.DisplayAlerts = false; // No prompt when overriding

  // Create a new workbook (index=1) and open source workbooks (index=2,3,...)
  Workbook destinationWb = app.Workbooks.Add();
  foreach (var sourceFilePath in sourceFilePaths)
  {
    app.Workbooks.Add(sourceFilePath);
  }

  // Copy all worksheets
  Worksheet after = destinationWb.Worksheets[1];
  for (int wbIndex = app.Workbooks.Count; wbIndex >= 2; wbIndex--)
  {
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks[wbIndex];
    for (int wsIndex = wb.Worksheets.Count; wsIndex >= 1; wsIndex--)
    {
      Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[wsIndex];
      ws.Copy(After: after);
    }
  }

  // Close source documents before saving destination. Otherwise, save will fail
  for (int wbIndex = 2; wbIndex <= app.Workbooks.Count; wbIndex++)
  {
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks[wbIndex];
    wb.Close();
  }

  // Delete default worksheet
  after.Delete();

  // Save new workbook
  destinationWb.SaveAs(destinationFilePath);
  destinationWb.Close();

  app.Quit();
}
```

---

**Edit:** notice that you might want to `Move` method instead of `Copy` in case you have dependencies between the sheets, e.g. pivot table, charts, formulas, etc. Otherwise the data source will disconnect and any changes in one sheet won't effect the other.

Comment: This works brilliantly, many many thanks!

Just one thing: I changed
"for (int wbIndex = 2; wbIndex <= app.Workbooks.Count; wbIndex++)"
to
"for (int index = excel.Workbooks.Count; index >= 2; index--)"

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Office Autmation libraries in C#.
[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) is a sample code to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter Odbcda;

//CSV File
strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + SourceLocation + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";

sqlSelect = "select * from [" + filename + "]";

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());

conn.Open();
Odbcda = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sqlSelect, conn);
Odbcda.Fill(ds, DataTable);
conn.Close();
```

- This would read the contents of an excel file into a dataset.
- Create multiple datasets like this and then do a merge.

Code taken directly from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10071169/how-can-merge-two-excel-file-in-net.aspx).

Comment: But here you have not mentioned the excel extension(.xls). So how to mention the excel file extension.

One more thing, can it be save the values into the dataset as sheet by sheet and also when we will write into excel can it will come as sheet by sheet ?

Please write a set of code so that I can perform my above questions task. Waiting for your response. If possible please help me, its quite urgent....