# How to delete worksheets from Excel workbook in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, worksheet

Let's say I have one workbook which is having 6 sheets as Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6.

So from here I want to delete Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can call the [.Delete() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9kdkks3.aspx), like that:

```
Globals.Sheet1.Delete();
```

Update, according your comment:

```
Excel._Worksheet ws = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
ws.Delete();
```

Comment: When I am running this, it is throwing an error as "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Globals' does not exist in the current context". Please clarify me...

Comment: @Tripati Subudhi `Globals` refers to your workbook, and Sheet1 - for the first worksheet. You should add your own variables to make this code work. Also see the MSDN.

Comment: Please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376964/how-to-merge-two-excel-workbook-into-one-workbook-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top
Here it is generating the workbook dynamically by merging existing workbooks but when it is generating it was having 3 default sheets apart from merged worksheets. So here I need to delete that default three sheets.

Comment: @Tripati Subudhi Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code will help you:

```
app.DisplayAlerts = false; 
worksheet.Delete(); 
app.Displayalerts = true;
```

where *app* is your XlsApplication.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN knows:

```
((Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[4]).Delete();
```

or

```
Globals.Sheet1.Delete();
```

See here: [How to: Delete Worksheets from Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9kdkks3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: When I am running this, it is throwing an error as "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Globals' does not exist in the current context". Please clarify me..

And also when I am running above one then also I am getting error as " CS1061: 'System.Web.HttpApplicationState' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveWorkbook' and no extension method 'ActiveWorkbook' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpApplicationState' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: and what if you try the first option? did you read the linked article?

Comment: Please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376964/how-to-merge-two-excel-workbook-into-one-workbook-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top
Here it is generating the workbook dynamically by merging existing workbooks but when it is generating it was having 3 default sheets apart from merged worksheets. So here I need to delete that default three sheets. Please help me out on this...

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your example ([How to merge two excel workbook into one workbook in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376964/how-to-merge-two-excel-workbook-into-one-workbook-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top)), where *app* is your variable of type *Excel.Application*, you should write something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    ((Excel.Worksheet)app.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Delete();
```

P.S: it seems to me that the Worksheets collection is indexed starting from 1, not 0, but I'm not sure and can't check right now. If it doesn't work try with values for i from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s1 as Excel.Worksheet
s1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
s1.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible
s1.Delete()
```

You need to change visibility because you can't delete a sheet with the visibility set to Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden