# Create new excel worksheet with filestream from c# reportviewer

Tags: c#, excel, reportviewer, filestream

I have this code to [render a reportviewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252207%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\output.xls", FileMode.Create);

foreach (ReportViewer report in this.reports)
{    
    byte[] bytes = report.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

fs.Close();
```

My problem is that only the first report is viewable in the excel file with the name of the report as the worksheet name. *It appears as though the rest are there* (the file size increases) but just not formatted correctly.

**How do I make each report go into a different worksheet?**

Notes:

I tried adding a [device info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373.aspx) string to for startpage = 0 but that didnt help either.

I am trying to avoid using an extra library to accomplish this, it is part of a very lightweight program.

Similar unanswered question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763129/how-to-export-data-to-excel-via-reportviewer-with-multiple-named-worksheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out..

- Create an excel object with an empty workbook
- Render each report to the output file
- After rendered, load the file into the excel object as another workbook
- Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each report (overwriting the excel file)
- Copy each workbook into the first
- Save the workbook over the desired file

Kinda crazy, but it works and only uses the file specified by a savefiledialog so its all safe and good to go:

```
FileStream fs = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = null;
try
{
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    app.Workbooks.Add("");

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string extension;

    // Uses a string of comma separated ints to determine which reports to print
    foreach (string indexChecked in Properties.Settings.Default.PrintAllReports.Split(','))
    {
        // Create temp file
        fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] bytes = this.reports[Convert.ToInt32(indexChecked)].LocalReport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
        fs = null;
        // Add copy of workbook
        app.Workbooks.Add(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

    // Process each workbook and combine
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376964/how-to-merge-two-excel-workbook-into-one-workbook-in-c
    for (int i = app.Workbooks.Count; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        int count = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count;
        app.Workbooks[i].Activate();

        for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
            ws.Select(Type.Missing);
            ws.Cells.Select();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range sel = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)app.Selection;
            sel.Copy(Type.Missing);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets.Add(
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
            );

            sheet.Paste(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            sheet.Name = ws.Name;
            Clipboard.Clear();
            app.Workbooks[i].Close();
        }
    }

    // Remove it if it exists, we already asked once
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            // It will ask and then overwrite in the next step if the delete failed
        }
    }
    app.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);
    app.Workbooks[1].Close();
    app = null;
}
catch (IOException)
{
    // uses a wrapper method
    this.showErrorDialog("Report Generator cannot access the file '" + saveFileDialog1.FileName + "'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n\u2022 The file name or path does not exist.\n\u2022 The file is being used by another program.");
}
finally
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
    if (app != null)
    {
        app.Workbooks.Close();
    }
}
```

Any input/feedback is welcome.